# In Eclipse/CVS how to update a branch from head?

Tags: eclipse, cvs

We use CVS with Eclipse.  There has been code changes that are committed to HEAD. I need to update a branch with the changes from HEAD.  How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The [Merging from a branch](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-100b.htm?cp=0_3_16_2_5) help topic covers this.